# wget -k -p -r exampleserver.com doesn't download images?

Tags: wget

Title says it all. I try to download a page with wget -k -p -r and it downloads .html .js and robots.txt only. I need those images as well. They didn't land in my folder. What's wrong? I used same command on another page and it did what i wanted.

Comment: Add -H option and it works.

Comment: It does not. It only downloaded a ton of crap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add -H option and it works. -H is for Host

No it does not. It only downloaded a load of crap.